# SQL : Summing the values in a column till first non zero values appears in other column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose, I have a table t1 looking like

| id | value1 | value2 | wk_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 5 |

And I want to sum up the value1 till non-zero value appears on the value2 for first time.
End product must look like this:

| id | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 |

How to perform this in SQL?

Comment: The problem is that table data is an unordered data set. Do you have a column to determine the order? A datetime column maybe? Then, why do you tag two different DBMS? Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah, dataset has a datetime column. Updated the dataset

Answer (score 2):

If your MySQL version support window function you can try to use `SUM` window function with condition aggregate function be a flag to represent your logic (till non-zero value appears on the value2 for first time)

Then do condition aggregate function again.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 0 THEN value1 ELSE 0 END) value1
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         SUM(CASE WHEN value2 = 1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY wk_id) flag
  FROM T 
) t1
GROUP BY id;
```

| id | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fSKBsctrQ7M4Bpv5pCvyYD/0)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, when we did sum over the partitions, why flag is not -1 for the entries having value2 as zero initially. Should not it be -1 for all the rows of an id if there is any non-zero value2 ? Why it behaves like a rolling sum ?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN SUM(value2) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY wk_id) = 0
                THEN SUM(value1) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY wk_id) 
                ELSE 0
                END sum_value1
    FROM test
    ORDER BY id, wk_id
)
SELECT id, MAX(sum_value1) sum_value1
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fcdca008e4a821f952de4d608434bcf

Answer (score 0):

One option is a `NOT EXISTS` clause, looking for the stop row (the first row with value2 = 1).

```
select id, sum(value1)
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select null
  from mytable stoprow
  where stoprow.id = mytable.id
  and stoprow.wk_id <= mytable.wk_id
  and stoprow.value2 = 1
)
group by id
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating on a calculated rolling total of value2 can also be done via a self-join.

> ```
> select id
> , sum(if(roll_tot_value2=0,value1,0)) as total
> from 
> (
>   select t1a.id, t1a.wk_id, t1a.value1
>   , sum(t1b.value2) as roll_tot_value2
>   from t1 as t1a
>   join t1 as t1b
>     on t1b.id = t1a.id
>    and t1b.wk_id <= t1a.wk_id
>   group by t1a.id, t1a.wk_id, t1a.value1
> ) q
> group by id;
> ```

| id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8899e54e384730002a2c6e32e1cfcc7b)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.id, coalesce(
   (select sum(t2.value1) from t1 t2 where t2.value2 = 0 and t2.id = t.id 
       and (not exists (select 1 from t1 t3 where t3.value2 = 1 and t3.id = t.id) 
       or t2.wk_id < (select min(t4.wk_id) from t1 t4 where t4.id = t.id and t4.value2 = 1))), 0) 
from t1 t group by t.id
```